# How do I alter a row in a mySQL query result?

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I want to iterate through a bunch of mySQL rows in Python and, after I process each row, alter it:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT someNonUniqueColumn,hasBeenProccessed 
                FROM myTable WHERE hasBeenProcessed = 0")
for row in cursor:
    # use someNonUniqueColumn for something...
    ...
    # set "hasBeenProccessed" to 1
```

I'd like to avoid the ugliness of:
- having to execute another SQL query each time I process a record, or
- fill an array with the ID's of rows as I process them
(Both of which would require that I add a unique key to the table)

So, is there a way to "check these off as I go"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to change a row in-pace. There's a number of reasons for this, one of them is that values returned by a query may be not updatable: think counts, sums and other aggregate functions.

If you do just a very small amount of database interaction, saving IDs and issuing a compound `update` statement seems best.

If you issue more than 1-2 queries in your program, do yourself a favor and learn SQLAlchemy or Django ORM. Neither is completely transparent, but either will save you massive amounts of time and debugging pain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run a query after you do the changes/processing

```
UPDATE myTable SET hasBeenProcessed = 1 WHERE hasBeenProcessed = 0
```

If this is possible of course :)

Comment: But it would be unfortunate if some other code has added further rows with `hasBeenProcessed` is zero since this code made its original query ... remember that databases are multi-user.